# Convert a 2D circle image to a 3D cylinder object

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I wrote this code to generate random data :

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 32), np.linspace(0, 1, 32))
X = xx
Y = yy
Z = np.random.rand(32, 32)

##### MASK : SQUARE IMAGE => CIRCLE IMAGE ######
N = 32
m = (N-1)/2
mask = np.ones((N,N))
D = 80
a = D/N
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if (i-m)**2+(j-m)**2 < (D/2/a)**2:
            mask[i][j] = 0
################################################
plt.imshow(np.ma.masked_array(Z, mask))
#plt.contourf(X, Y, np.ma.masked_array(Z, mask), zdir='z', offset=0.5, levels=100)
plt.show()
```

**Output :**

[image]

I want to convert the image to a cylinder object. It is like having multiple (same) stacked circle images.

***Another Example :***
1.
[[image]]

2.
[[image]]

Comment: Do you want pixel data or mesh data? The two examples you show are quite different and thus would require different approaches to make work.

Comment: @meetaig Thank you for your reply. I want pixel data. Since it is a matrix for both cases, the approach shouldn't be that much different, no ?

Comment: mesh data can be stored in an array, but works very differently than pixel data in this case. or you first create a pixel array and then convert to mesh using some premade function from a library. But in any case it would require extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to just make a stack of pixel data, this should work for you

```
z_height = 100
mask3 = np.stack([Z*(1-mask)]*z_height, axis=2)
```

This just repeats the circle with the random data `z_height` times along the z axis and assigns the result to a new array `mask3`.

Note that I took the liberty of simplifying the assignment. The mask array you created did not actually contain any of the pixel data, so I multiplied Z with the inverse of the mask.

You could also assign 1 instead of 0 to the mask locations you want to preserve, then you'd simplify the above code.

If you want a textured mesh, that is a whole different story and would require some more work that I cannot whip up as quickly as this :D

**edit:**

here is the output of the above code:

[image: output jupyter]

Comment: Can you show me your output ? because i've got an error : MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 1024, mask size is 102400.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my output. Simply used `mask` and `Z` from the code snippet you provided.

Comment: I see the problem. ma_masked_array expects 2d data. so you have to input slices of the 3d stack if you want to visualize it, just like what i did when i plotted it

Comment: Yes exactly, but i don't want to look to one slice at a time, I want to plot a full cylinder (as it is shown in the example). So maybe plot all the 100 slices in a 3D plot ?

Comment: I will leave that as an exercise to the reader. maybe this will help:
https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/